# Is it okay to reduce DHT in my body?

Tags: hairloss, hormonal-imbalance

DHT may also has some roles in our bodies. If we keep its level as low as possible, I think it must begin to affect negatively. I'm specifically worrying about the negative effect regarding mind and mentality, since I'm a graduate student in science.

Depending on the method of lowering DHT level, I think it may affect the testosterone concentration too, and it will certainly cause problems.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For what reason would you be looking to reduce DHT levels? For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: In addition to @ChrisRogers' comment, I would caution you that asking for medical advice is off topic here. Asking about DHT levels in general is fine, but asking about how it might affect you personally is not.

Comment: I am voting to close this question due to the fact that there is [no indication of prior research](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and there has been no response to requests for it

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that dihydrotestosterone (DHT) does much more than contribute to hair loss. It also plays a crucial role in male sexual development and mood regulation. When DHT levels are reduced, either intentionally or unintentionally, it can impact these functions in unwanted ways and cause:

Impotence,
Lower sex drive,
Difficulty achieving orgasm,
Abnormal ejaculation,
Gynecomastia (male breast development),
Depression.

However, these side effects only appear in a small minority of men. As with any medication, you should discuss with your hair loss physician whether DHT blockers or other pharmaceutical treatments offer a viable and effective option for addressing your hair loss issues.

References:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3481923/

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4064044/

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5023004/

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4339524/

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences! As OP doesn't spell it out and our audience is wide, please spell out DHT, [perhaps once](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/972/11231)?